# join multiple files efficiently

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort, join

I know there are some posts to join multiple files but it took so much time. I have multiple files in which the first columns are for the patients' IDs, then I want to join multiple files, based on the ID numbers in the first column.

The codes as below still work, but it took so much time. Thus, does anybody know more efficient way of doing this process?

```bsh
for PHENO in A B C D E F G H I J K L M
do
    join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto chr2_${PHENO} chr3_${PHENO} >${PHENO}
done

for PHENO in A B C D E F G H I J K L M
do
    for file in chr5_${PHENO} chr11_${PHENO} chr14_${PHENO} chr20_${PHENO} \
    chr21_${PHENO} chr22_${PHENO} chr6_${PHENO} chr9_${PHENO} chr13_${PHENO} \
    chr18-1_${PHENO} chr18-2_${PHENO} chr1-1_${PHENO} chr1-2_${PHENO} \
    chr1-3_${PHENO} chr8-1_${PHENO} chr8-2_${PHENO} chr17-1_${PHENO} \
    chr17-2_${PHENO} chr19-1_${PHENO} chr19-2_${PHENO} chr19-3_${PHENO} \
    chr19-4_${PHENO} chr4-1_${PHENO} chr4-2_${PHENO} chr4-3_${PHENO} \
    chr4-4_${PHENO} chr7-1_${PHENO} chr7-2_${PHENO} chr7-3_${PHENO} \
    chr10-1_${PHENO} chr10-2_${PHENO} chr10-3_${PHENO} chr10-4_${PHENO} \
    chr12-1_${PHENO} chr12-2_${PHENO} chr12-3_${PHENO} chr12-4_${PHENO} \
    chr15-1_${PHENO} chr15-2_${PHENO} chr15-3_${PHENO} chr16-1_${PHENO} \
    chr16-2_${PHENO} chr16-3_${PHENO}; do
        join -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto ${PHENO} "$file" >${PHENO}.1
        mv ${PHENO}.1 ${PHENO}
    done
done
```

All the files as as below. 150001 patients, showing whether they have a disease or not as 0 or 1.
For example, chr2_${PHENO}

```
ID Disease
1 0
2 1
3 0 
4 1
5 1
....

150000 0 
150001 1
```

For example, chr3_${PHENO}

```
ID Disease
1 1
2 1
3 1 
4 0
5 0
....

150000 0 
150001 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can we have an indication of the file sizes? There appear to be roughly 50 files that you want to join, will all 50 fit in ram at the same time? You have a "-e 1" in your code, is this actually used? You also have "-o auto", is this needed? A big plus for join is that it can handle billions of lines even on small machines as essentially it only needs to hold one line from each file in memory at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the examples of each file.

Comment: Sample files are not sorted ... *"Important:  FILE1  and  FILE2  must  be sorted on the join fields."* - and you do not sort on join. What is missing here? And: does each file have same range of ID's (no holes)?

Comment: Thank you. If sorted, no need to add -a1 and -a2?

Comment: That depends on what you want as a end-result. If you do not include -a1 and -a2, then any ID missing from FILE1 that is in FILE2 is not going to be printed and vice versa. Say ID 5 is in FILE1 but *not* in FILE2. Then omitting *-a1* will exclude the line with *ID 5* all together. If it is needed depends on two things. If you want it to be omitted and if the files have holes? As in can file1 have ID `1, 2, 4, 5` and file2 ID `2, 3, 4, 5` ? File1 missing ID 3 and file2 missing ID 1?

Comment: Yes, File1 missing ID 3 and file2 missing ID 1. For PHENO, each ABDEF,,, has different number of patients. What I want to make is all the results, based on the patients for each disease, ABCDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is *not an answer per se*, but a post to perhaps clarify things.

Incorporate what you need into your question.

(And sorry, know it is not how things are normally done, but ...)

---

#### Does this resemble your files and needed result?

Here are two sample scripts. The first to generate dummy files:

- *chr1_A* to *chr6_A*
- *chr1_B* to *chr6_B*
- *chr1_C* to *chr6_C*

Sorted by using `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1b,1`

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
for p in A B C; do
    for i in $(seq 1 6); do
        f="chr${i}_$p"
        printf 'ID %s\n' "$i.$p" >"$f"
        paste <(shuf -n 24 -i 1-222) <(shuf -n 24 -i 0-1 -r) | \
            LC_ALL=C sort -k 1b,1 >>"$f"
    done
done
```

Giving a sample group like: `paste chr* | column -t`

```
ID   1.A  ID   1.B  ID   1.C  ID   2.A  ID   2.B  ID   2.C  ...
116  1    107  1    101  0    110  1    105  1    111  0    ...
126  1    11   1    105  0    111  1    106  1    117  1    ...
131  1    111  0    106  0    121  0    113  0    121  0    ...
141  0    133  0    110  0    124  0    147  0    145  0    ...
167  1    135  1    113  1    135  0    154  0    146  1    ...
...
```

Not sure if this is correct, you decide.

---

Second script is a modified version of yours (e.g. using dash for missing so that it is distinguishable from real data):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for PHENO in A B C; do
    join -a1 -a2 -e - -o auto chr1_${PHENO} chr2_${PHENO} >${PHENO}
done

for PHENO in A B C; do
    for n in 3 4 5 6; do
        file="chr${n}_$PHENO"
        join -a1 -a2 -e - -o auto ${PHENO} "$file" >${PHENO}.1
        mv ${PHENO}.1 ${PHENO}
    done
done
```

Resulting in three files A, B and C:

```
$ paste A B C | column -t
ID   1.A  2.A  3.A  4.A  5.A  6.A  ID   1.B  2.B  3.B  4.B  5.B  6.B  ID   1.C  2.C  3.C  4.C  5.C  6.C
10   -    -    1    1    -    -    101  -    -    1    -    -    1    101  0    -    0    -    -    1
100  -    -    -    0    -    -    102  -    -    -    -    -    0    103  -    -    -    -    -    0
102  -    -    1    -    0    -    105  -    1    0    -    0    -    105  0    -    -    -    -    -
108  -    -    0    -    -    -    106  -    1    -    -    -    1    106  0    -    -    -    1    -
109  -    -    -    -    -    1    107  1    -    -    -    -    -    107  -    -    -    -    -    0
110  -    1    -    -    -    -    109  -    -    -    -    -    0    108  -    -    -    -    -    0
111  -    1    -    -    -    -    11   1    -    -    -    -    -    109  -    -    -    1    0    -
116  1    -    -    -    -    -    111  0    -    -    -    -    -    110  0    -    -    -    -    -
117  -    -    -    -    1    -    113  -    0    -    -    -    -    111  -    0    -    -    -    -

...

# or
# paste <(sort -n A) <(sort -n B) <(sort -n C) | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach:

1. Make sure all files like `chr1_A` have the full 15000 entries, sorted! This also includes filling with "1" where missing.
2. Reduce each of these files to the "Disease" column only.
3. Make a file with the "ID" column for each PHENO.
4. Paste instead of join the now reduced files with the ID-Column one. (They are sorted and lines must match as of point 1)
5. Create script to parallelize.

Howto:

1. +2. Via `awk`-script, name it e.g. `fillrows.awk`

   ```
   NR>1 {disease[$1]=$2}
   END {print FILENAME
        for (i=1;i<=15000;i++) {
          if (disease[i]!="")
             {print disease[i] > FILENAME"_red"}
          else {print "1" > FILENAME"_red"}
        }
   }
   ```

This would make a file `chr1_A` like

```
 ID Disease
 2  0
 5  1
```

To `chr1_A_red` (6 lines max shown)

```
 chr1_A
 1
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

when executed as: `awk -f fillrows.awk chr1_A`

3. ID-column is always the same

   ```
   { echo ID ; seq 1 15000 ;} > ID_col
   ```
4. Paste together - this may be limited depending on RAM:

   ```
   for PHENO in {A..M} ; do
     paste ID_col chr*_$PHENO > $PHENO
   done
   ```
5. Some parallelizations via [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    ##get chrX-Y list without PHENO
    find -name 'chr*' | sed 's/_.$//' | sort -u > chrlist
    parallel awk -f rowfill ::: chr*{A..M}
    { echo ID ; seq 1 15000 ;} > ID_col
    parallel paste ID_col '{1}_{2}_red' '>' '{2}' :::: chrlist ::: {A..M}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a recursive function to join an arbitrary number of files:

```bsh
join_all() {
    local -a join_opts
    local arg
    while :; do
        arg=$1
        shift
        [[ $arg == '--' ]] && break
        join_opts+=("$arg")
    done

    if (($# == 1)); then
        cat "$1"
    else
        join "${join_opts[@]}" "$1" "$2" | join_all "${join_opts[@]}" -- '-' "${@:3}"
    fi
}


for PHENO in A B C D E F G H I J K L M
do
    files=()
    # use brace expansion to generate the list of files
    files+=( chr{2,3,5,11,14,20,21,22,6,9,13}_${PHENO} )
    files+=( chr{18,8,17}-{1,2}_${PHENO} )
    files+=( chr{1,7,15,16}-{1,2,3}_${PHENO} )
    files+=( chr{19,4,10,12}-{1,2,3,4}_${PHENO} )

    join_all -a1 -a2 -e 1 -o auto -- "${files[@]}" > ${PHENO}
done
```